# Basic Ethernet Home Network Cabling

Tags: router, ethernet, home-networking, cable, cable-modem

I am trying to set the Ethernet ports around my parents house (CAT 5e) but I am a bit confused as to how to go about it. They’re currently just using wifi with a basic xfinity router/modem. I have found where I think all the ports lead to (as seen in picture) but I can’t seem to figure it out and the documentation is really bad. Who should i contact about getting all the ports connected to the modem, and what could be the costs? Any other tips or information is appropriated, thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently wired for landline telephone service, but if you don't need landline telephone service (first make sure any professionally monitored alarm system/service you might have isn't using it, because I see an alarm system RJ31X jack that looks like it might have a cable connected) you could easily repurpose some or all of them for Ethernet by disconnecting them from that telephone-style punch-down block and connecting them to 8P8C (RJ-45) modular keystone jacks that slot into a patch panel, or another kind of punch down Ethernet patch panel. Then you would use normal Ethernet patch cables to connect from there to a gigabit Ethernet switch, and then connect one port of the switch to a LAN port on the router. This is easy DIY territory; you shouldn't need to call an electrician or telecom cabling installer for this little job.

Comment: Thank you for all thank info! We do have separate phone jacks throughout the house so may this be for the phone jacks only and not the Ethernet cables?